# Calculate the total in array php

Tags: php

I would like to calculate the total of a result of several tables in PHP, here is my array.

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [reference] => 000000092
            [firstname] => utilisatrice
            [lastname] => test
            [total_products_wt] => 1500.000000
            [date_add] => 2018-04-04 14:53:18
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [reference] => 000000093
            [firstname] => Filleul
            [lastname] => test
            [total_products_wt] => 1500.000000
            [date_add] => 2018-04-04 14:58:33
        )

)
```

Based on value `total_products_wt`

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What's the problem?

Comment: Do you want sum of all values of `total_products_wt`?

Comment: Yes i need sum all values of total_products_wt

Comment: Loop the array with `foreach` and sum each element with the index `total_products_wt` in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of [`array_column()`](https://php.net/array_column) to get all values of the keys `total_product_wt`. Then use [`array_sum()`](https://php.net/array_sum) to compute the sum of theses values.

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'reference' => '000000092',
        'firstname' => 'utilisatrice',
        'lastname' => 'test',
        'total_products_wt' => '1500.000000',
        'date_add' => '2018-04-04 14:53:18'
        ),
    array(
        'reference' => '000000093',
        'firstname' => 'Filleul',
        'lastname' => 'test',
        'total_products_wt' => '1500.000000',
        'date_add' => '2018-04-04 14:58:33'
        )
);

$total = array_sum(array_column($array, 'total_products_wt'));
echo $total;
```

Outputs:

```
3000
```

Comment: Great answer. I would note that the output is still a float (decimal), in case further operations are performed or the number is intended to be stored in a database. array_sum returns floats if floats are used to sum.

Comment: Thank you @citrusy. I don't really understand what is the issue here. The total can be transformed after the sum, to perform other operations if needed.

Comment: It can, it can also throw you off depending on what exactly you're trying to do with the number. Some calculating functions only work with integers. A database column set for integers will give an error if you try to store a float in there. I love php's dynamic types most of the time, but it's not been my experience that floats auto-convert for functions that only take integers so it is important to keep track of these types. Otherwise, it's easy to forget that it needs to be transformed or alternative method used in order to use as intended. I'm all for avoiding bugs when possible.